# Destructuring of an array of objects getting undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have tried to destructure the Array object, getting undefined.

```
 var menus = [{
   food: "pizza",
   drink: "coke"
 }, {
   food: "burger",
   drink: "pepsi"
 }, {
   food: "sandwitch",
   drink: "coke"
 }, {
   food: "popcorn",
   drink: "coke"
 }];

 var {
   food: team,
   drink: sports
 } = menus;

 console.log({
   team
 });
```

Output: team is undefined.

It seems like a syntax issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to destructure an object inside the array.

You can use array destructuring with object destructuring (the 1st item in this case):

```js
const menus = [{"food":"pizza","drink":"coke"},{"food":"burger","drink":"pepsi"},{"food":"sandwitch","drink":"coke"},{"food":"popcorn","drink":"coke"}];
 
const [{ food:team,drink:sports }] = menus;
 
console.log({team});
```

Or destructure a specific object in the array:

```js
const menus = [{"food":"pizza","drink":"coke"},{"food":"burger","drink":"pepsi"},{"food":"sandwitch","drink":"coke"},{"food":"popcorn","drink":"coke"}];
 
const { food:team,drink:sports } = menus[2];
 
console.log({team});
```

To get all values to a new array use `Array.map()`:

```js
const menus = [{"food":"pizza","drink":"coke"},{"food":"burger","drink":"pepsi"},{"food":"sandwitch","drink":"coke"},{"food":"popcorn","drink":"coke"}];
 
const teams = menus.map(({ food: team }) => ({ team }));
 
console.log(teams);
```

Comment: After destructuring , i have get a first value alone , how can get all the values of food and push into new array

Comment: thank you for the valuable answer i have learned destructuing from you..